# How do i assign particular post for particular page using wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have create separated page says "service.php" with following code

```
<?php /* Template Name: services */ ?>
......//code
......
```

So the above page now act as separate static page.
now i want to assign particular post for this service page in wordpress.

Is it possible to do that?

Kindly advice on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no other querys on the page...

Simple...

```
<?php query_posts('p=5'); ?>

   <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
      <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

         <!-- Do stuff here -->                 

      <?php endwhile; endif; ?>   
   <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Where it says P=5 - that's the post id number.